# I use Stateless Widget alongside BLoC almost everytime. Am I wrong?

Tags: flutter, timer, bloc, statefulwidget, statelesswidget

I am having a hard time understanding how to deal with states in some specific situations with Flutter.

**For example**, say I need a page where the click of a button fetches data from an API. Such a request could take time or any kind of problems could happen. For this reason, I would probably use the BLoC pattern to properly inform the user while the request goes through various "states" such as `loading`, `done`, `failed` and so on.

**Now**, say I have a page that uses a `Timer` to periodically (every 1sec) update a `Text` Widget with the new `elapsed time` value of a `Stopwatch`. A timer needs to be properly stopped (`timer.cancel()`) once it is not used anymore. For this reason, I would use a `Stateful` Widget and stop the timer directly in the `dispose` state.

**However**, what should one do when they have a page which both :

- Fetches data from API and/or other services which require correctly handling states.
- Uses a `Timer` or anything (streams ?) that requires proper canceling/closing/disposing of...

**Currently**, I have a page which makes API calls and **also** holds such a `Timer`. The page is dealt with the BLoC pattern and the presence of the `Timer` already makes the whole thing a little tedious. Indeed, creating a BLoC "just" to update a `Timer` feels a little bit like overkill.

**But now**, I am facing a problem. If the user doesn't go through the page the "regular" way and decides to use the "back button" of his phone: I never get to cancel the `Timer`. This, in turn, will throw the following error: `Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.`

Indeed, even after having `pop()` to the previous page, the `Timer` is still running and trying to complete its every 1sec duty :

```dart
Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      (Timer t) {
        context.read<TimerBloc>().add(const Update());
      },
    );
  }
```

Could someone please explain to me how such "specific" situations should be handled? There must be something, a tiny little concept that I am not totally understand, and I can feel it is slowing me down sometimes.

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: How and when do you define and store the timer in the case where you get the error you describe? Could you present that piece of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, this is opinionated.

Even though you've described a lot, it is a bit tricky to follow your cases and how you've (specifically) implemented it. But I'll give it a shot at describing things to consider.

There are several ways to handle this. I'll try to answer your questions.

1. There is nothing wrong with always or only having Stateless widgets and Blocs.
2. There is nothing wrong with combining Stateful widgets and Blocs.
3. Consider the case with a page with both a bloc and e.g. a Timer updating a particular text field on that page. Why should one widget handle both? It sounds like the page could be stateless (using the bloc), that has the text field in it, but that text field could/should perhaps be a separate StatefulWidget that only hold the timer, or equivalent. Meaning that sometimes people put to much responsibility in one huge widget, when it in fact should be  split into several smaller ones.
4. I don't understand why you would face that error, it is no problem having both a bloc and a timer in a stateful widget, with poping and using backbutton with proper disposal and timer being reset. See the full code example below.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const FirstPage(),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('First page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => BlocProvider<FetcherCubit>(
                    create: (context) => FetcherCubit(),
                    child: const SecondPage(),
                  ),
                )),
            child: const Text('Second page')),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SecondPage> createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  late final Timer myTimer;
  int value = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myTimer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        value++;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    myTimer.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Second page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Timer value: ${value.toString()}'),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => context.read<FetcherCubit>().fetch(),
              child: const Text('Fetch!'),
            ),
            BlocBuilder<FetcherCubit, FetcherState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                late final String text;
                if (state is FetcherInitial) {
                  text = 'Initial';
                } else if (state is FetcherLoading) {
                  text = 'Loading';
                } else {
                  text = 'Completed';
                }
                return Text(text);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FetcherCubit extends Cubit<FetcherState> {
  FetcherCubit() : super(FetcherInitial());

  Future<void> fetch() async {
    emit(FetcherLoading());
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    emit(FetcherCompleted());
  }
}

@immutable
abstract class FetcherState {}

class FetcherInitial extends FetcherState {}

class FetcherLoading extends FetcherState {}

class FetcherCompleted extends FetcherState {}
```

The result if you build it:

[image]

Comment: First thank you very much for your complete answer ! It helped me how to solve my problem a whole lot better.

Comment: So sorry, I am very new to StackOverflow I clicked on `Enter` and it automatically sent my comment (and then I took more than 5min to edit it).

I am still facing a problem tho. Say, as you proposed, I have my `Timer` in a separate `Stateful` Widget which allows me to `cancel` it when needed in the `dispose` state. What if (and it is sadly my case) I also need the `tick` value of this `timer` for the API call I will do through my BLoC ?

I think I am having a hard time understanding how a "parent" Widget can access informations of its "children" Widgets, like in the example given above.

Comment: If you have further problems that should be treated as separate questions though. Try to isolate the questions and close them when the specific question is solved, or at least you where able to move forward from the specific problem you had. Otherwise the questions might never get closed :) and it is easier to find help on small specific issues than too large ones. So I suggest to close this question and open a new one with your specific "new" problem :)

Comment: But, a short answer to your concern here. You can do it in many ways. But one way would be to inform the bloc about the tick in the timer, after you've increased it. I.e. doing something like: `context.read<FetcherCubit>.reportTick(value)`, and that method either acts on the tick straight away, or your store it in the state of the bloc, and so forth... basically up to the requirements...

Comment: Indeed, I asked a separate question on the forum (see: [How to interactif with a child Stateful Widget from a parent Stateless Widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477545/how-to-interactif-with-a-child-stateful-widget-from-a-parent-stateless-widget). I understand the solution you are offering me here, but I do not quite understand how I can "technically" apply it. I really think I shouldn't have been using `Stateless` so much because anything seems quite "complex" to implement for me now. Typically here, I wouldn't know how to provide `FetcherCubit` to a `Stateful` Widget.