# How to interact with a child Stateful Widget from a parent Stateless Widget?

Tags: flutter, timer, stopwatch, statefulwidget, statelesswidget

**Context :**

Say I have a custom `DisplayElapsedTime` Widget which is `Stateful` and holds a `Text` Widget. With a `Timer`, every 1sec, the text value is updated with the current `elapsed` time given by a `Stopwatch`.

And now, say I have a page which is `Stateless` and has the `DisplayElapsedTime` Widget as a child.

**What I would like to do :**

1. On the click of a "Start" button in my page, I would like to start the `DisplayElapsedTime` (which means starting the `Stopwatch` and the `Timer`).
2. From my page, I would also like to have access to the `elapsed` time value of the `Stopwatch` "whenever I want".

**Why I am having a hard time :**

So far (see: [I use Stateless Widget alongside BLoC almost everytime. Am I wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74465273/i-use-stateless-widget-alongside-bloc-almost-everytime-am-i-wrong/74466908#74466908)), I have almost always worked with `Stateless` Widget alongside the pattern BLoC and never used `Stateful`. Currently, having extremely long and complex Widgets, I am starting to sense the "limits" of not using the better of the two worlds. But I don't quite fully understand how the Widgets should be interacting between one another.

I really cannot find the solution to my problem anywhere (or am really bad at searching). However, surely, I cannot be the first person to want to have "control" over a `Stateful` Widget from a `Stateless` Widget, right ?

Thank you so much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, let me try to explain this using the most familiar app of all time, the beginning counter app.

This snippet contains a single StatefulWidget that controls its ability to rebuild using its *setState* method *_incrementCounter*. So, the value is incremented and the widget is rebuilt whenever the *StatefulWidget* calls the *setState method* inside itself.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

A **StatefulWidget** can fully rebuild itself, and when doing so, it may also rebuild all its children downstream of it in the widget tree (but not always, as const widgets are not rebuilt). To get another widget to rebuild a parent widget (upstream of it in the widget tree), you need to have that StatefulWidget's *setState* function. This can be done using a *callback function*. A *callback function* is made by the parent widget and passed to a child widget. So, in the following example, I have made a *StatelessWidget* with a *button*, which controls its parent widget because it calls its parent's *callback function*; notice that I give:

```
ExampleStlessWidget(counter: _counter, fx: _incrementCounter),
```

and not:

```
ExampleStlessWidget(counter: _counter, fx: _incrementCounter()),
```

Passing *_incrementCounter()* with the parenthesis calls it at the moment it is passed, while *_incrementCounter* allows it to be called downstream in the widget tree.

Use the *callback function* in the child widget by calling it anywhere (notice the parentheses).

```
onPressed: () {
                fx();
              },
```

Here is the new code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ExampleStlessWidget(counter: _counter, fx: _incrementCounter),
    );
  }
}

class ExampleStlessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExampleStlessWidget({
    super.key,
    required int counter,
    required this.fx,
  }) : _counter = counter;

  final int _counter;
  final Function fx;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
              Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            fx();
          },
          child: const Text('Click me'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

A *bloc* involves an **inherited widget**, which allows for monitoring the state throughout the widget tree and rebuilds widgets depending on that state. So, a bloc doesn't need a *StatefulWidget* to change UI. It would help if you did not look at one tool's ability to rebuild widgets as bad or good. It would be best to look at StatefulWidgets and *BLoC* as different tools for different jobs.

I hope this helps. Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me ! I will try what you offered and come back to you as soon as possible !

Comment: If you were to post a viable single-code snippet with what you are trying, we may be able to help you out further.

Comment: Yes I realize it is difficult to totally understand what I'm asking without seeing some code. I will try to post it and add further indications regarding what I'm looking for ! Could you just indicate to me what would be the most correct way to do that on Stackoverflow ? Should I "answer to my question", create a new post, or something else ?

Comment: i think you could edit your original post by adding more to that post and then leave a message that you have updated the original post.

Comment: Really useful answer.  It deserves to be the part of official flutter tutorial.